# How do I apply SSL certs to my React app and Spring boot server?

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, ssl, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

I have deployed my project on a compute engine VM instance. React is running on some port and Spring Boot server is running on another port. I've downloaded certs for a subdomain on the VM. How do I apply them to the project so that it opens on HTTPS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We get PEM file from [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) using certbot

```
certbot certonly -a standalone -d example.com
```

Create PKCS12 format using openssl

```
 openssl pkcs12 -export -in fullchain.pem -inkey privkey.pem -out keystore.p12 -name tomcat -CAfile chain.pem -caname root
```

Add these properties to application.properties to add SSL certificate from [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/)

```
server.port: 443
security.require-ssl=true
server.ssl.key-store:/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/keystore.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password: store-password
server.ssl.keyStoreType: PKCS12
server.ssl.keyAlias: tomcat
```

Comment: thanks. But since react's my front end, I'll need react to run on 443. Do I need to add some to the react start script or something as well?

Comment: If react is served from spring boot tomcat static folder then you don't need to do anything as tomcat will serve the index html file over https

Comment: No that's not the case. that's why I was a little confused.

Comment: Do you have separate web server to serve your react index html and js files ? If so then add ssl to that web server using nginx as reverse proxy and add ssl to spring boot to enable https to your rest API calls

Comment: Yes I have a seperate web server for react. Thanks. I'll try that. Just to confirm, do I have to add ssl to spring-boot as well? and what port do I give it since react will run on 443?

Comment: You can run your spring boot on 8443  and make sure your react app points to https://rest-api-boot-server:8443/api/**  and if same host then  https://127.0.0.1:8443/api/** to make your rest api calls

Answer (score 0):

You may install NGINX on your instance and use it as a reverse proxy to pass requests to each server depending on the subdomain, then you may update the configuration with SSL config.

If you plan on using certificates issued by [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/), then you can use [Certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/) to amend the NGINX configuration with SSL config automatically.